# Erro durante atualização do Eclipse: "unable to connect to repository"

Tags: java, eclipse

Quando tento instalar uma nova atualização do Eclipse em "Available Software" aparece o seguinte erro:

> Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/content.xml
>
> Connection to download.eclipse.org refused

Já liberei o firewall, mas o erro persiste.

Answer (score 1):

Sem detalhes sobre o teu sistema, acesso à internet e versão do Eclipse, existem duas coisas que podes verificar para tentar resolver a questão:

1. #### Dar preferência ao IPv4

   Com base na mensagem de erro, o problema costuma estar relacionado com a maneira como é feita a ligação ao servidor `download.eclipse.org`.

   Podes no teu [`eclipse.ini`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> adicionar o seguinte:

   ```
   -vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
   ```
2. #### Verificar Port

   Podes aceder às definições de rede e verificar qual a porta que está indicada para ser utilizada:

   > Window → Preferences → General → Network Connections

   Deverá estar a porta 80 que é a por-defeito.

   Também deverás prestar alguma atenção à configuração da rede para saberes que port(s) de saída estão autorizadas.